# How do you automatically rfkill unblock all on startup?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, wicd, rfkill

I am an Ubuntu/Linux newbie, trying to overcome a range of issues, but eagerly learning a lot in the process. With help of this forum I was able to identify and solve the problem of getting my wireless to work. Basically I discovered that it would work if I replaced Network Manager with WICD, and then typed "rfkill unblock all" into the command terminal. This sets "Hard blocked" from yes to no, and then everything works great. I could still unblock the hard block when I had Network Manager but for some reason it still wouldn't work. Only with WICD would it work. So I'd recommend anyone struggling with getting their wireless to work to try WICD.

My problem is that the Hard block is set back to yes every time I restart my laptop. I do have a "hard" switch for the wireless, but it's a toggle key on the keyboard (Fn + F7), so its not really that "hard" actually. So every time Ubuntu starts up I have to open the command terminal again, type "rfkill unblock all" then open WICD and ask it to connect (even though it's set on connect automatically). I was wondering  if anyone could teach me how to make this process happen automatically on start up? Because of the intended use of this computer I have to restart often. Alternatively, is there anyone who would be interested to help me find the root of my problem? I.e. why the computer always boots up with the hard block set to yes?

Hopefully solving either of these would also cause WICD to automatically connect on start up too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your command in the file `/etc/rc.local` (before the `exit 0`) or create a startup script and put it in `/etc/init.d`

Comment: Hi, sorry I never replied. Somehow I thought I had opted to receive updates on this post via email, but I hadn't! So just wanted to thank you belatedly and say that it worked! Slowly getting to grips with all this now...