# I have to issue "rfkill unblock wifi" at every boot

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, interface, rfkill

Config: Laptop, standard working wifi card, Ubuntu 14.04

At every boot, Wifi/Wlan is off/SoftBlocked, I can get it to work with the command `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`

but after every reboot I have to re-issue that command again (actually that's not entirely true, sometimes (5%) it seems to "stick" through a reboot).

Is there a way to tell rfkill to never block wifi, without having to tell it so explicitly every time?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/356622/how-do-you-automatically-rfkill-unblock-all-on-startup?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

You can make a service to do this. Execute the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/rfkill-unblock-wifi.service
```

then, copy and paste the following into the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=RFKill-Unblock WiFi Devices

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wifi
ExecStop=
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Finally, execute the following command to enable start up the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable rfkill-unblock-wifi.service
sudo systemctl start rfkill-unblock-wifi.service
```

Hopefully this doesn't start before wifi is blocked.

[source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155282)

Comment: Thank you. I have been interested in the way you way you do it, I did it in another service of mine, but this didnt work cause NetworkManager blocks it back - I dont know when -. I solved my problem with writting `rfkill unblock wifi` in **rc.local** to ensure it is unblocked at the very end of boot.   It works ok. It block def' **after** it is blocked.

Comment: Actually, there are already an init script for storing and restoring rfkill:
/etc/init/rfkill-store.conf and /etc/init/rfkill-restore.conf

Comment: @senz It seems that script simply "restores" the previous state. If this ends up "restoring" to an incorrect state, you can always edit those files accordingly to explicitly unblock instead. I used to be a sysvinit guy myself but I really like the systemd ability to enable, disable, and mask services.

Comment: ArchLinux forums? The forum for amateur Linux users who hold a huge ego?

Comment: @bsound I think you have arch confused with manjaro.

Comment: @mchid Certainly not.

Answer (score 5):

I tried mchid's answer and it didn't work for me because NetworkManager was killing the wifi *after* startup finished.

What did work was `nmcli r wifi on`

What appears to be the root of the problem is that somewhere along the line the "Enable WiFi" menu item in the GUI got unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

In the kernel cmdline put `rfkill.default_state=1`. This works irrespective of the init-system and doesn't require ugly script hacks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this nightmare configuring a **Dell Edge GW** as an AP, using the package ***hostapd***. When Googling I saw lots of folks complaining about soft blocks when configuring an AP in various forums. Various different hacks were offered as work-arounds, but none of the posts really identified the root cause of soft blocks.  After lengthy analysis I found how it was breaking.

Although some parts of the below answer are specific to the ***Dell Edge*** / ***hostapd*** config, it's still worth reading as it gives great insight into how/why a soft block is thrown.

### Short Answer: Soft blocks occur when processes collide accessing radio

ie: ***NetworkManager*** is using the radio because it controls the GSM ***wwan0*** interface. But when ***hostapd*** tries to access the radio via the ***wlan0*** IF which is **NOT** managed by ***NetworkManager*** [because they don't play well with each other](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#NetworkManager_is_interfering)- they come into conflict.  ***NetworkManager greedily covets the radio and if anything else tries to use it, NetworkManager*** spitefully throws a soft block

Although the solution may sound obvious- uniformly manage radio access within one interface management system- this is not so straight forward:

- ***NetworkManager*** as noted above is to be avoided when using ***hostapd***
- ***systemd-networkd*** can neither be used with ***hostapd***. After realizing ***NM*** couldn't be used to manage the ***wlan0*** interface, when I tried to config ***systemd-networkd*** instead, I found that wouldn't work either:  ***ERROR: wlan0: networkd does not support wifi in access point mode***

When using ***hostapd*** for your AP, the WiFi IF (usually ***wlan0***) should be raised using `ip` commands AFTER and ***NM*** finished (and ensure nothing else restarts ***NM***).  I found doing a `rfkill unblock all` before and after raising the ***wlan0*** IF with scrripted IP commands cleared the soft block allowing the ***wlan0*** IF to start correctly which inturn allowed ***hostapd*** to start normally on reboot.

### Long Answer:

Some specifics as to how I arrived at my conclusions in the short answer above.

1. **IF Management**: For their Edge gateway, Dell has enabled in their 18.04 image BOTH ***systemd-networkd*** AND ***NetworkManager***, but in ***Netplan*** defaulted the IF management to the later.  You'll remark a standard 18.04 install only has ***systemd-networkd*** as the default for IF management.
2. The wrapper for configuring an AP with ***hostapd*** "[create_AP](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/blob/master/create_ap)", unhooks the WiFi interface from ***NM*** control and uses `ip link set` commands to raise the WiFi IF (line #1697 in above link). Although "_create_ap)" was part of Dell's 16.04 image, it's no longer present in the 18.04 image leaving the user to manually config the AP.  *This is where the fun begins*
3. Having configured the GSM interface ***wwan0*** successfully within ***NM***, I configured the WiFi IF ***wlan0*** in ***NM*** also.  This failed for the same reasons "***create_ap***" and Arch Linux unhook it as I later found in the prev referenced links for ***NM***.   So per the Arch Linux instructions, I added the directive `unmanaged-devices=mac:<hwaddr>` for the ***wlan0*** in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to ensure ***NM*** didn't cause any further havoc with it.
4. Realizing ***NM*** was a non-starter for configuring ***hostapd***, I next configured the ***wlan0*** IF to be managed by ***systemd-networkd***.  However, the following error puked revealed that wouldn't work with ***hostapd*** either: ***ERROR: wlan0: networkd does not support wifi in access point mode***. I was quickly losing the will to live.  Had I not turned in my Glock when I left NYPD I probably would have self-harmed...
5. Neither ***NM*** or ***systemd-networkd*** being an option to manage the ***wlan0*** interface, I was only left to configured it `ip` commands.  And this worked- **MANUALLY**.  However, on reboot, the soft block was thrown, despite unhooking ***wlan0*** from ***NM***.  ***So if NM isn't throwing the soft blocks now, what is?!?!?***
6. Further analysis revealed ***NM*** was still in play. I found ***dhcpcd.service*** had a ***NM*** hook when it started, so a restart of the dhcpcd client would get ***NM*** rearing it's ugly head.  `ps aux` revealed this was happening: `/sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-eth0.pid`
7. I discovered that anything that caused ***NM*** to kick-in would cause the soft block to be thrown.  So in my scripts I removed anything that called for ***NM*** to restarted or anything that called for ***dhcpcd.service*** to be restarted.  But yet the problem **STILL PERSISTED**.
8. Although manually raising the ***wlan0*** IF succeeded in allowing ***hostapd*** to rise-up correctly, a reboot caused the soft block which will stop the ***wlan0*** IF from starting until it's cleared.
9. So the only solution I was able to arrive at was to raise the ***wlan0*** IF AFTER ***NM*** had finished and ensure nothing else restarted ***NM*** once ***wlan0*** was up. In my scripts I added a `rfkill unblock all` both *before* and *after* the start of the `wlan0` IF using `ip` commands.  **THIS FINALLY WORKED**.
10. You might think: "***Terrence, why not try to moderate the behaviour of dhcpcd.service in its' unit file rather than hacking in scripts!***" Preferring elegant solutions to hacks, I looked into this: it's not possible to persistently edit that ***dhcpcd.service*** as the file is dynamically generated and doesn't persist across reboots!! Execute `find / -name dhcpcd.service` and you'll see the unit files describing this service exist in /run. Crack one open and you'll be told: ***# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator***

Commands I scripted to stop ***NM*** from hogging the radio :

```
sed -i "/managed=true/a unmanaged-devices=interface-name:$INTERFACEAP" /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

nmcli radio wifi off
```

Commands I scripted to raise the ***wlan0*** IF using IP commands, independent of both ***NM*** and ***systemd-networkd***:

```
rfkill unblock all
ip addr add $IPV4IPWLAN0 dev $INTERFACEAP
ip link set $INTERFACEAP up
rfkill unblock all
```

Although I've got ***hostapd*** finally working, I'm going to therapy 7 days a week now and my therapist says I'm progressing well to get over the experience.  Anyhoo, hope I saved others from this living hell...

Answer (score 0):

I just added a start-up programs entry to block wifi. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75irC.png)